# how can i count digits of a number using recursion?

Tags: c++

yes i know other ways to count digits and returning to main function from the recursion function, but i'd like to print it in the void function. im having difficulty with it. could somebody help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void recursive_function(int num)
{
    int sum=0;
    while(num!=0){
        recursive_function(num/10);
        sum++;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    recursive_function(345289467);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _but i'd like to print it in the void function_ Why?  The natural thing to do is to return an `int` and print it in `main`, why fight it?

Comment: Each time you call the function recursively, It will print the sum value. Use Int rather than void and print the value in the main function rather than a recursive function.

Comment: Also, you have a `while` loop that never terminates. Don't you mean to use an `if` instead?

Comment: Your question code is both iterative and recursive, and never terminates and never terminates!

Comment: How many digits does the number `0` have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use the return-stack to count your digits, you will need to pass the current count throughout the call stack as function parameter:

```
void recursive_function(int num, int count=1)
{
    if (num>=10) {
       recursive_function(num/10, count+1);
    } else {
       cout<<count<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, but I just realized that there are negative `int`s too so `num>=10` should probably be `std::abs(num)>=10`.

Answer (score 1):

your recursive function should return integer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int recursive_function(int num)
{    

    if(num>9){
        return 1+recursive_function(num/10);        
    }else
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    cout << recursive_function(123456789);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int rec_fun(int x,int c){
    if(x==0 ){
        if(c==x)
            c=1;
        return c;
    }
    return rec_fun(x/10,++c); 
}

int main() {
    cout<<rec_fun(1566,0);
    return 0;
}
```